# Auth::guard('admin')->user() return always null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I define a new guard "Admin" to have a multi Auth System User and admin in my project . when i login it is ok and i get the token to the rest of my api routes .When when I use The auth::guard('Admin')->user() i got always null

Any suggestion??

Auth.php :

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',     
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport', 
        'provider' => 'users', 
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ]
],




'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
```

Login method  :

```
public function ALogin(Request $request){

    //  dd($request);
    //  dd($rrequest->header);

     if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {
        $this->connectedAdmin = Auth::guard('admin')->user(); 
        // dd( $connectedAdmin);
         $success['token'] = $this->connectedAdmin->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken; 
         $return = new \stdClass();
         $return->token = $success['token'];
         //dd(self::$connectedAdmin);
         return response()->json($return, 200); 
     }

      // dd(Auth::guard('admin')->user());
     return response()->json("error", 400); 
 }
```

*/

Comment: also in the api.php i need to know how to specify routes to group routes with specifc admin guard and token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your route file, to specify a guard for several endpoints you coud do:

```
/** routes/api.php */

Route::group(['guard' => 'admin'], function () {

    Route::get('/a-route', 'AController@method');
    // ...

});
```

Comment: i did it HCK but i get alwayes null   
//get Connected Admin 
  //Route::get('admin/Connected','Auth\LoginController@connected');
  Route::group(['guard' => 'admin'],function ()
  {
  
    Route::get('admin/Connected','Auth\LoginController@connected');
  
  });